# bash, tee in a named pipe?

Tags: bash, pipe, tee

The following code:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
mkfifo pipe 2>/dev/null
tee pipe >/dev/null &
cat pipe
```

produces no output when run as follows:

```
$ echo "hi" | ./test.sh
+ mkfifo pipe
+ cat pipe
+ tee pipe
$
```

Why?! I would expect `tee` to copy stdin to the named pipe (and `/dev/null`), and then `cat` to copy the contents of the named pipe to stdout. Why doesn't it work?!

I'm trying to write a bigger bash script and I really need the `tee` in there, with something else in the place of `/dev/null`. I narrowed down the unexpected behaviour to the example above.

Comment: try changing to `unbuffer cat pipe`. You may have to search for machine for unbuffer, and either call with the full path, or add the path to your PATH variable. OR, rather than echo "hi", cat a pretty big file into your ./test.sh. Good luck.

Comment: I tried `./test.sh <~/.xsession-errors`, which is about 1Mb, still nothing.

Comment: Weirdly, `cat | tee pipe >/dev/null` works as expected. But why?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you background a process its standard input will be set to `/dev/null`

```
#!/bin/bash -x
mkfifo pipe 2>/dev/null
cat - | tee pipe >/dev/null &
cat pipe
```

So you need to specify you want the `stdin` of the parent, in your case the pipe between `echo` and `./test.sh`